# I'm looking for materials or links about cross-compiling, like eabi, etc

Tags: arm, sensors, cross-compilation

I'm looking for materials or links about cross-compiling, like eabi, etc. I'm new to Linux-based cross-compiling, and I want to develop my knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Install the ARM cross compiler toolchain on Ubuntu](https://www.acmesystems.it/arm9_toolchain):

> How to install on Ubuntu the complete toolchain to cross compile the
> Linux kernel, the Linux device drivers, the Linux applications and the
> boot loader like as AT91Bootstrap and its derivatives like AcmeBoot
> and AriaBoot.
>
> This procedure has been tested on Linux Ubuntu 16.04. The same ARM cross compiler toolchain
> is in the default Ubuntu repositories up of Ubuntu 16.04-20.04.
>
> ###Install the Cross Compilers, utilities, etc.
>
> Install the GCC, G++ cross compilers and support programs by typing:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install libc6-armel-cross libc6-dev-armel-cross
> sudo apt install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi
> sudo apt install libncurses5-dev
> ```
>
> If you are using an [Arietta](https://www.acmesystems.it/arietta),
> [Aria](https://www.acmesystems.it/aria) or [FOX
> G20](https://www.acmesystems.it/FOXG20) board:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
> sudo apt install g++-arm-linux-gnueabi
> ```
>
> If you are using an [Acqua](https://www.acmesystems.it/acqua) or
> [RoadRunner](https://www.acmesystems.it/roadrunner) board:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
> sudo apt install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf
> ```
>
> Now you are ready to cross compile on your PC all the source available
> for the Acme Boards based on Microchip MPUs.
>
> ###Try the cross C compiler
>
> Let's try to cross compile a Hello World example in C and running it
> on an Acme board.
>
> This is the example:
>
> ```
> #include "stdio.h"
>  
> int main(void) {
>   printf("Hello world!\n");
>   return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Compile it typing:
>
> ```
> arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c -o hello
> ```
>
> As you can see we are using the ARM version of gcc just installed on
> your PC. It will generate an executable file for your Linux board.
>
> Copy the executable file on the board via ssh:
>
> ```
> scp hello root@[your_board_ip]:/root
> ```
>
> Then open a command session on your board and run the example:
>
> ```
> ./hello
> Hello world!
> ```
>
> ###Try the cross C++ compiler
>
> Let's try to cross compile a Hello World example in C++ and running it
> on an Acme board.
>
> This is the example:
>
> ```
> #include "iostream"
>  
> using namespace std;
>  
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
>     cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Compile it typing:
>
> ```
> arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ hello.cc -o hello
> ```
>
> As you can see we are using the ARM version of gcc just installed on
> your PC. It will generate an executable file for your Linux board.
>
> Copy the executable file on the board via ssh:
>
> ```
> scp hello root@[your_board_ip]:/root
> ```
>
> Then open a command session on your board and run the example:
>
> ```
> ./hello
> Hello world!
> ```

All of the packages in this tutorial are also in the default Ubuntu 14.04 repositories.

###Links specific to nRF51, LM35 and Arduino

- nRF51 microcontroller - https://arduino.stackexchange.com/search?q=nRF51
- LM35 temperature sensor - https://arduino.stackexchange.com/search?q=lm35
- Arduino - [What does it take to compile Linux on Arduino, if at all possible?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-does-it-take-to-compile-linux-on-arduino-if-at-all-possible)

Comment: could you please provideme some more specific l

Comment: like interfacing a sensor with the microcontroller please

Comment: What are the sensor and microcontroller models, so that I can check the platform being targetted (e.g. ARM)?

Comment: yes microcontroller like nrf51 and sensor lm35

Comment: nrf51 is a ARm cortex M0 with BLE

Comment: actually i want to make this one with Embedded linuxis there anypossibilities

Comment: This isn't working in Ubuntu 18. Is an updated package set available?

Comment: This is a comprehensive, and quality answer. very well done.